# Codeigniter model foreach pass array to controller -> to view

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is my model - I want to assign the rows and echo out on the view page e.g `<?php echo $product?>`

```
class Model_products extends CI_Model {

    function printer()
    {

    $id = $this->uri->segment(3, 0);

        $q = $this->db->get_where('printer', array('id' => $id));

        if ($q->num_rows == 1)
        { 
            foreach ($q->result() as $row)
            {

                echo $row->name; # THIS WORKS
                $data['product'] = $row->name;  # THIS DOES NOT WORK
                $data['desc'] = $row->description;
                $data['size'] = $row->size;
                $data['options'] = $row->options;
                $data['more'] = $row->more_info;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Here's my controller

```
public function products()
{

    $this->load->model('Model_products');

    $this->Model_products->printer();

    $this->load->view('products', $data);

    $this->load->view('pricing');
}
```

My view is

```
<h1>
<?php echo $product; ?>
</h1>

<p>
<?php echo $desc; ?>
</p>


<h3>
Size
</h3>
<p>
<?php echo $size; ?>
</p>
```

**How do I properly pass my model array to my controller so that I can echo out on my view?**

Comment: in controller,give `$data = $this->Model_products->printer();
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply return $data to controller

```
class Model_products extends CI_Model {

    function printer()
    {
        $data   =   array();
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3, 0);

        $q = $this->db->get_where('printer', array('id' => $id));

        if ($q->num_rows == 1)
        { 
            foreach ($q->result() as $row)
            {

               // echo $row->name; # THIS WORKS
                $data['product'] = $row->name;  # THIS DOES NOT WORK
                $data['desc'] = $row->description;
                $data['size'] = $row->size;
                $data['options'] = $row->options;
                $data['more'] = $row->more_info;
            }
        }

    return $data;
    }
}
```

No win Controller

```
public function products()
{

    $this->load->model('Model_products');

    $data['products']   =   $this->Model_products->printer();

    $this->load->view('products', $data);

    $this->load->view('pricing');
}
```

And in view

```
<?   
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($products);
?>
```

EDIT Also correct your model code.

```
        foreach ($q->result() as $row)
        {

            echo $row->name; # THIS WORKS
            $data[]['product'] = $row->name;  # THIS DOES NOT WORK
            $data[]['desc'] = $row->description;
            $data[]['size'] = $row->size;
            $data[]['options'] = $row->options;
            $data[]['more'] = $row->more_info;
        }
```

If you are not using multidimensional array it will overwrite the last record.

Answer (score 0):

Where your return statement

```
if ($q->num_rows == 1)
    { 
        foreach ($q->result() as $row)
        {

            echo $row->name; # THIS WORKS
            $data['product'] = $row->name;  # THIS DOES NOT WORK
            $data['desc'] = $row->description;
            $data['size'] = $row->size;
            $data['options'] = $row->options;
            $data['more'] = $row->more_info;
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

and/or in your controller

```
public function products()
{ 
   $this->load->model('Model_products');
   $data = $this->Model_products->printer();
   $this->load->view('products', $data);
   $this->load->view('pricing');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the data from the model back to the controller and then from there, pass the data to the view.

In your model function, place a return statement at the end.

```
return $data;
```

Then in your controller, assign the returned value from the model to a variable.

```
$data = $this->Model_products->printer();
```

Those 2 steps should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used @raheel's code and it works. But I would just change a bit:

```
   $i=0;
   foreach ($q->result() as $row)
        {


            echo $row->name; # THIS WORKS
            $data[$i]['product'] = $row->name;  # THIS DOES NOT WORK
            $data[$i]['desc'] = $row->description;
            $data[$i]['size'] = $row->size;
            $data[$i]['options'] = $row->options;
            $data[$i]['more'] = $row->more_info;
        }
```

This will help extracting the data